# Can't find where keystore file for android is located

Tags: android, ant, cmd, keystore

can someone please help me out with this problem i'm having while building my android project from command line.

I want to use ant to build the project at signed mode. for that i need
key.store=path/to/my.keystore
key.alias=mykeystore

can someone please tell me where i can find these 'path to my keystore' and 'mykeystore' informations !!! This is really getting me crazy!! and i'm stuck because of this.

So if anyone knows the answer can you please share...:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Signing for Release Mode](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode).

The private key and it's information is created by you, and not provided by Google. The exact steps are detailed in the above link. The Google tools are only responsible for the debug keystore.